# Telerik RadGridView: column value is edited when TextBox from RowDetails reaches MaxLength

Tags: c#, telerik, silverlight-5.0, radgridview

I have a Silverlight 5 project that uses Telerik `RadGridView`.
This `RadGridView` has `RowDetails`, which contains editable `TextBox`. If I paste some text in this `TextBox` several times till it reaches `MaxLength`, first column in selected grid row is automatically edited with excess text.
Has anyone seen and fixed this?

To try out, here`s some sode:

**XAML**

```
<telerik:RadGridView Name="gvMain" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <telerik:RadGridView.ChildTableDefinitions>
    <telerik:GridViewTableDefinition />
</telerik:RadGridView.ChildTableDefinitions>

<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" />
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding PageCount}" />
</telerik:RadGridView.Columns>

<telerik:RadGridView.HierarchyChildTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <TextBlock>Name</TextBlock>
           <TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.Author.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel}}" 
                    MaxLength="20" Width="100" />
       </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:RadGridView.HierarchyChildTemplate>
```

**Models**

```
public class Author
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public int PageCount { get; set; }
   public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

**Code behind**

```
this.gvMain.ItemsSource = new List<Models.Book>()
  {
     new Book(){ Author = new Author(){ Name = "John", LastName = "Smith"}, 
                 Title = "Dummy", PageCount = 100}
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that when `TextBox` or `ComboBox` in RowDetails cannot paste text from clipboard (when `MaxLength` is reached for example) they stop precessing pasting events which are relayed to row itself. Ard so row inserts pasted text.

Solution that we implemented is to replace TextBoxes with custom ones that have only this additional code:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
 {
     if (IsPastingAndClipboardTextIsTooLarge(e.Key))
     {
        int textToFit = (MaxLength - Text.Length + SelectionLength);
        if (textToFit > 0)
        {
           var startIndex = SelectionStart;
           var textToPaste = Clipboard.GetText().Substring(0, Math.Min(textToFit, Clipboard.GetText().Length));
           int caretPosition = startIndex + textToPaste.Length;
           if (SelectionLength > 0)
              Text = Text.Remove(startIndex, SelectionLength);

           Text = Text.Insert(startIndex, textToPaste);
           SelectionStart = caretPosition;
        }

        e.Handled = true;
     }
     else base.OnKeyDown(e);
  }

  public bool IsPastingAndClipboardTextIsTooLarge(Key key)
  {
     return key == Key.V && ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control) &&
            Clipboard.ContainsText() &&
            Text.Length + Clipboard.GetText().Length > MaxLength - SelectionLength;
  }
```

But `ComboBoxes` will require some code too.
If there`s a better solution please let me know!